# Definition of weak solutions to the Neumann's problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

An exercise in Evans PDE is the following.

> Let $\Omega$ be connected. A function $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ is a weak solution
> of Neumann's problem
> \begin{equation}
> (*)\qquad\left\{
> \begin{array}{rl}
> -\Delta u = f & \text{in } \Omega \\
> \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = 0 & \text{on } \partial \Omega
> \end{array}
> \right.
> \end{equation}
> if
> $$
> \int_\Omega Du \cdot Dv \; dx = \int_\Omega fv \; dx
> $$
> for all $v \in H^1(\Omega)$. Let $f\in L^2(\Omega)$. Prove $(*)$ has a weak solution
> if and only if
> $$
> \int_\Omega f \; dx =0.
> $$

I'm confused with the definition of weak solutions to the Neumann's problem. In my opinion, similar to Dirichlet's problem, the weak solutions are defined as the following.  Let $$X(\Omega)=\left\{u\in H^1(\Omega)\mid \int_\Omega udx=0\right\}.$$
(The space $X(\Omega)$ is similar to $H_0^1(\Omega)$ in the Dirichlet's problem.) We say that a function $u\in X(\Omega)$ is a weak solution of $(*)$ if
$$\int_\Omega Du \cdot Dv \; dx = \int_\Omega fv \; dx$$
for all $v\in X(\Omega)$. Then we can show that for any $f\in(X(\Omega))^*$, we can find a weak solution $u\in X(\Omega)$ of $(*)$ by Poincare's inequality and Riesz representation theorem. What are the disadvantages of this definition?

Answer (score 1):

Well, suppose $u$ is a smooth solution to your problem (also $f$ smooth), then we know by integration by parts that $$\int_{\Omega}(-\Delta u) v\,dx+\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}v\,dx=\int_{\Omega} fv\,dx,$$ for all $v \in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ with $\int_{\Omega}v\,dx=0$ (even $v \in X(\Omega)$ but this is not needed). First taking $v \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, and then general $v$ for the boundary condition, we only find that $u$ solves the equation $$\begin{cases} -\Delta u = f - c & \text{in $\Omega$},\\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0 & \text{on $\partial \Omega$}, \end{cases}$$
for some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$. In fact, since $$\int_{\Omega} -\Delta u\,dx = \int_{\Omega} -\textrm{div}\nabla u\,dx = -\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\,dx=0, $$ this constant $c$ is exactly $\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}f\,dx$. Therefore, even in your setting the assumption $\int_{\Omega} f\,dx=0$ should be imposed to solve the Neumann problem. Since the Neumann problem is invariant under translations by constants, the condition $\int_{\Omega}u\,dx=0$ may be used to make the solution unique, although this is not necessary.